# Verify JWT Token Signature in traefik

Tags: jwt, microservices, token, traefik

I am implementing a microservices architecture, I have an oauth2 service that does the authentication and generates a token for me.

I am using Treafik as an API-Gateway

How do I validate that a token has expired and that the token signature is valid?

I am testing with those tags in my docker-compose but it seems to ignore it

```
labels:
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-jwtAuth.plugin.jwtAuth.source=jwtSource"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-jwtAuth.plugin.jwtAuth.forwardHeaders.Group=grp"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-jwtAuth.plugin.jwtAuth.forwardHeaders.Expires-At=exp"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-jwtAuth.plugin.jwtAuth.claims: Equals(`grp`, `admin`)"
```